# Terminal errors when running my project code, which uses GPIO

Tags: button, pygame, gpio, orange-pi

I have a school project to create code in Arduino on the OrangePi PC model. The objective is for the code to make three buttons play an audio, where you must pause, rewind and fast forward. For this I used the OPi.GPIO libraries to configure the pins, and pygame for the buttons. But I have made a lot of mistakes, as I am not at all an expert at this.

The error that appears in the terminal is the following:

```py
_frozen_importlib:219: RuntimeWarning: Your system is neon capable but pygame was not built with support for it. The performance of some of your blits could be adversely affected. Consider enabling compile time detection with environment variables like PYGAME_DETECT_AVX2=1 if you are compiling without cross compilation.
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.0.8, Python 3.6.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codigoOPi.py", line 11, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OPi/GPIO.py", line 480, in setup
    raise e
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OPi/GPIO.py", line 472, in setup
    sysfs.export(pin)
  File "/home/orangepi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OPi/sysfs.py", line 37, in export
    with open(path, "w") as fp:
```

The code I built is this:

```py
import OPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
import pygame

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

proximo = 7;
pausa = 8;
volta = 9;

GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT);
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT);
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT);
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP);
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP);
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP);

GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH);
GPIO.output(8, GPIO.HIGH);
GPIO.output(9, GPIO.HIGH);

pygame.mixer.init()
caminho_do_audio = "/home/orangepi/msc/"
pygame.mixer.music.load(caminho_do_audio)

def iniciar_pausar_callback(pausa):
    print("Botao iniciar ou pausar pressionado")
    if pygame.mixer.music.getbusy():
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

def adiantar_callback(proximo):
        print ("botao de adiantar pressionado")
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(pygame.mixer.music.set_pos() + 10)
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        
def retroceder_callback(volta):
    print("botao retroceder pressionado")
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(pygame.mixer.music.set_pos() - 10)
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

gpio.add_event_detect(8, GPIO.FALLING, callback=iniciar_pausar_callback, bouncetime=300)
gpio.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.FALLING, callback=adiantar_callback, bouncetime=300)
gpio.add_event_detect(9, GPIO.FALLING, callback=retroceder_callback, bouncetime=300)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("programa encerrado pelo usuario")
finally:
        gpio.cleanup()
```

I believe that the circuit has no error, but just in case I leave here a Tinkercad link demonstrating a little of how it is:

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/huVmXOblYqK-projetobiosemfroteiras

If you know of a different method that might be easier to program something like this, I would be grateful for the advice and any help you may have.

Comment: Don't use user space GPIO programming like this. Use `gpio-keys` Linux kernel driver for the buttons. It will be much more performant and have a standard interface (`libinput` or alike). It appears I already told you that and you haven't followed the advice. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, the other question was closed so I didn't look further, I'll try your suggestion

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: @USER How do I use gpio-keys? I tried searching but nothing is clear, the orange.pi manual doesn't help either

Comment: With my last comment I posted a **template** (one should use exact nickname they want to notify) for the user notifications. Read a bit of documentation on what features are available on SO (in the context of comments, questions, answers, etc.).

Comment: Have you googled at least before asking? https://forum.armbian.com/topic/6723-gpio-keys-mainline-linux/, https://samyeer.net/2016/07/22/using-gpios-as-key-events-in-android/, and so on...

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for the assistance. Yes, I researched and came to a similar result, however, errors occurred that I cannot deduce what they are.

Comment: @0andriy I can't send it in the comment because it's too long, but I created another question about...